# Varchar to Date - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to load a csv file using bulk insert. My csv file has 4 date columns, which I think is causing the issue. The dates are in format `DD/MM/YY`, how do i change that to `DD/MM/YYYY`.  I need to import these date fields into a `date` column and not a `varchar`.

I am loading this file into a #temptable and then using the following code to insert it into a database table :

```
insert into table (a,b,c,d,e)

select a, 
       b,
       convert(date,c,103),
       convert(date,d,103),
       e
from #temptable
```

Not sure where im going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The column `c` in your temp table, is it type date or varchar?

Comment: yeah all columns in my temptable are varchar, becasue when i try to use bulk insert and load it straight into a table with date columns it gives me :
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage.
Thats why im loading it into a table with Varchar and then using convert()  to insert into the actual table

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SET DATEFORMAT**

**Example**

```
Set DateFormat DMY
Declare @D varchar(25) = '20/02/2018'

Select try_convert(date,@D)
```

**Returns**

```
2018-02-20
```

> **EDIT - Just for Fun**

If you set DateFormat to MDY, the try_convert will return null

```
Set DateFormat MDY
Declare @D varchar(25) = '20/02/2018'

Select try_convert(date,@D)
```

**Returns**

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format "changes" in the temp table, that is because they are already dates.  You can probably just do:

```
insert into table (a, b, c, d, e)
    select a, b, c, d, e
    from #temptable;
```

If that doesn't work, find the offending values:

```
select d, e
from #temptable
where convert(date, c, 103) is null or
      convert(date, d, 103) is null;
```